# Replacing regular twin shocks with nitrox for my bike

Tags: motorcycle, shock-absorber, bajaj

I have a bike with regular Twin shock absorbers (Spring and damper). I am planning to change this to  Gas charged shock absorbers. Since I used to ride my friend's [Bajaj Pulsar 150](http://www.bajajauto.com/pulsar150dtsi_index.asp), and it feels more comfortable than riding in my bike. Will it make my back comfortable when I change my regular shocks to a Nitrox (gas charged) shock used in the Pulsar.

I recently have asked a Pulsar dealer regarding the price of a pair of shocks which is close to 1750Rs.

Your suggestion will be of great help to me for my following questions:

1. Will it have any impact on my back if I change it to a pulsar's shock absorber?
2. Can I fit the shock absorber in an inverted fashion (like in Royal Enfields).
3. Will I be able to modify my existing shock absorber with a reservoir to be fitted in it. Is it feasible?

Comment: Hi Arun - you have 3 questions here: 1) will this make my back comfortable (ie softer shocks?), 2) pricing/recommendations, 3) Can I fit them inverted. Number 2 is off topic here, as per the [faq] but could you separate out 1 and 3 as separate questions so they can be answered, please.

Comment: @Rory Alsop: Ok Thanks... I will edit my question accordingly... But I do not want to split this into two different questions as I have to copy paste the same story to ask the second question...

Comment: You need to add your motorcycle's make and model to the question.

Comment: Installing shocks designed for another bike into your bike is not recommended as there are tons of factors which you will need to decide before installing the Main Being "Safety" the shocks can make your bike stiffer which will throw your back of the bike out if you are not careful , Basically Not a good Idea. (Although i have seen many idiots running Pulsar shocks on a Yamaha Rx135)

Answer (score 2):

Whether it can be done or not, I don't know, but it is unlikely that changing the shocks will significantly affect what you feel in your back. Comfort issues are far more likely to be caused by riding position, seat quality/age, and seat shape.

A friend of mine had similar problems due to an old seat and resolved them by cutting a memory-foam pillow to fit his seat and re-upholstering with the memory-foam as an added padding (keeping the original padding too).

I have always had trouble riding street-bikes because of the far forward riding position. This is why I ride a V-Max, you get the super speed and the comfortable riding position ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I used to ride an Avenger 180, 2006 model and the stock dampers were causing discomfort so I changed them with the shocks from a Yamaha Enticer. There was a paradigm shift in the ride quality, it became better, and the experience for the pillion rider was improved as well.

I now have an RE Thunderbird 350 n facing similar issues since I too have a back ache issues.
I am planning to use Pulsar 220 Nitrox gas shocks.

My advice is that if you have researched enough about your issue then go ahead and experiment with it and make adequate the changes in a scientific way. Not doing anything will not solve the issue at hand. I received similar recommendations from people that it would alter the bike design, change the force, this, that, blah blah blah... but I think that my
comfort is exponentially bigger than the bike n hence if there are any changes to be made then I will make it but by proper scientific calculations.

Anyway, all the best and man has made machines and not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ongoing physical problem with back pain, then it is unlikely you will find any combination of shock absorber to allieviate it when riding your motorcycle.

If the condition is severe should you even be riding a motorcycle in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do not have any permanent damages. My back is not feeling comfortable when I ride my bike... but felt the real difference in comfortness when I rode Pulsar 150.

Answer (score 1):

There are other factors such as stability, rigidity, maneuverability, dampening on which shocks are designed and fitted to a motorcycle. If you require a strict Yes/No answer, I cannot; moreover your current motorcycles make and model is not mentioned. Considering RoyalEnfields shocks replacement you should keep in mind that those shocks are designed to bear and absorb shocks from such a heavy machine.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I own a 110cc star city bike... Fitting a nitrox shocks to it in an inverted fashion do some help to my comfortness or will it make it worse?

Comment: I think you can use Series Spring Suspension found in the new TVS Phoenix which is advanced than that found on star(and again, you ought to check for the bolt axis measurements) because both bikes weigh almost the same. For less weighing Nitrox, Bajaj Discover series is available in India market at present.

Comment: Is pulsar's shock a good choice for my bike?

Comment: I'm not sure. But mostly no.

Answer (score 1):

1.You have not mentioned your vehicle make/model.(please mention it to answer your  question exactly)
2.The weight of pulsar 150 is approximately 135 kg and if your vehicle is a 100 cc it will be nearly 115 kg. So you will get stiffer suspension feel when you install it.
3.The damper(shock absorber) mounting points should match with your bike's mounting points and the length of damper also matters here or else you can't fit it.
4.Inverted and normal are nearly same as they have nearly same ride characteristics.
5.Adding a reservior to an existing non-reservior damper is a very difficult task and it may spoil the damper fully.

Please do mention your bike's model !!! or else your question is solutionless !!!

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts... So, if changing the rear shock of my bike is not worth then can you please suggest me a best tweak that I can make to bike to improve the comfortness in my ride .

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to add Pulsar shocks to star city dude!!

Measure the bolt axis (top mounting point) to bolt axis (bottom mounting point) length of your bike's shocks and Pulsar's, then compare them. If the length is nearly the same, you can use Pulsar shocks on your bike, but remember ride characteristics will change!! You'll feel bumpy rides!!